# Performance efficient way of checking if a controls text is empty

Tags: c#, text, string

Which among these 4 ways is the most efficient way for checking if a control's text is empty performance wise?

```
    someObject.Text != ""

    someObject.Text != string.Empty

    someObject.Text.Length != 0

    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(someObject.Text)
```

Comment: This is not your bottleneck. Ignore. (If you do not have a bottleneck and are just guessing: premature optimization is the root of all evil. [If not, benchmark. It's not hard.])

Comment: I would suggest that it largely doesn't matter, but your last check `IsNullOrEmpty` is redundant, the `Text` property is never null.

Comment: Testing Text.Length is cheapest.  The difference is a handful of nanoseconds.

Answer (score 4):

This is what we call *Premature Optimization*.

Short answer: Don't worry about it. Any of them is fine.